# Stop Python turtle onscreenclick() when drawing

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

Here is where my code goes wrong:

```
onscreenclick(Button.clicked,1)
listen()
mainloop()
```

onscreenclick() goes to Button.clicked, where it checks if the coordinates landed on any buttons. If so, it draws over them in the background color. However, if halfway through the erase process, the user clicks again, the erasing stops.

My question: Is there any way to make the onscreenclick() only work when the turtle is not drawing?

Cheers,
Jake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about just creating a variable that changes value on click?

Something like this:

```
isdrawing = False
if (Button.clicked == 1) and (isdrawing = False):
    isdrawing = True
elif (Button.clicked == 1) and (isdrawing = True):
    isdrawing = False
```

Then, you can check if the variable isdrawing is True or False and ask for certain value of it to run other functions.

Comment: Actually, I think yours was right, except I didn't show you enough of my code sorry.

Comment: No problem! Glad it works. Yeah, showing all the (relevant) code is good practice here.

Answer (score 0):

After a while, I figured out a solution:

```
import turtle as t

t.speed(1)
working = False

def drawShape(x, y):
    global working
    working = True ##True while drawing.
    t.goto(x, y)
    working = False ##false, drawing is over.

def clicked(x, y):
    global working
    if working == False: ##if turtle not drawing
        drawShape(x, y)

t.onscreenclick(clicked)
t.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a potentially simpler solution that I often use -- disable the event inside the event handler and reenable on exit:

```
import turtle

turtle.speed('slowest')

def drawShape(x, y):
    turtle.setheading(turtle.towards(x, y))
    turtle.goto(x, y)

def clicked(x, y):
    turtle.onscreenclick(None)
    drawShape(x, y)
    turtle.onscreenclick(clicked)

turtle.onscreenclick(clicked)

turtle.mainloop()
```

It also works well for the turtle cursor's `ondrag()` handler but make sure to use `turtle.speed('fastest')` when dragging!